# when I jump to the same viewcontroller from different navigationcontrollers, the Autolayout didn't work

Tags: ios, navigation, autolayout

As the title shows,I use the storyboard's auto-layout to layout a view controller,and then I jump to the view controller from different navigation view controllers.But only one view controller is auto shamed,the other one isn't. 
[image]

Comment: what you mean by "auto shamed"???

Comment: That means the view's size is changed by the screen's size,the view's size is not fixed.